# Windows 2003 - RAS service - VPN client can only connect to server, not internal network

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, routing, rras

Here is my diagram http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/263/vpnt.png/
Server has two NIC: One connect to Internet, one connect to internal network. RAS service is configured with static IP pool on the same subnet of internal network (10.10.0.x). The problem is when a client connect to server, client can connect to server(10.10.0.10), but cannot connect to another host locate in internal network (10.10.0.11) even cannot ping to 10.10.0.50.
RAS configured with IP routing enabled, client connect with options: Use default gateway on remote network.
I'm messed up and can not figure out what wrong. Please help me T_T.

TIA,
giobuon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agggg, I finally found that Trend Micro Office Scan client causes this. 
http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Win2000/microsoft.public.win2000.ras_routing/2006-09/msg00039.html

Anyway, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled "Allow callers to access my local network" (or something similar depending on the exact version of Windows) within the TCP/IP properties of your RAS server definition?

Comment: Can I enable it after created RAS server? I have to resolve this issue on remote system so I can't remove and recreate RAS. Thanks.

Comment: It's a "check box" within the TCP/IP properties, so no need to remove anything.

Comment: I'm using windows server 2003, and it seems do not have that option.

Comment: Within your RAS server/connector definition?